Setting up Microsoft Email and OAuth on osTicket
Good day everyone.
I have been trying to setup my email and OAuth on osTicket for a few days now. I followed the documentation here to setup the OAuth, but after I have followed through everything, filled all the required field, I click on Save and the page just turn white. I open Inspect Element, refresh the page and under Console I see error 500. I tried looking into the error logs for osTicket and I see the following:
[Tue Dec 17 15:18:17.770776 2024] [php:error] [pid 25331] [client 172.71.152.72:63892] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\choose_handler() in /var/www/osTicket/upload/include/plugins/auth-oauth2/lib/GuzzleHttp/HandlerStack.php:42
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/osTicket/upload/include/plugins/auth-oauth2/lib/GuzzleHttp/Client.php(65): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create()
#1 /var/www/osTicket/upload/include/plugins/auth-oauth2/lib/League/OAuth2/Client/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Client->__construct()
#2 /var/www/osTicket/upload/include/plugins/auth-oauth2/lib/League/OAuth2/Client/Provider/GenericProvider.php(104): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->__construct()
#3 /var/www/osTicket/upload/include/plugins/auth-oauth2/oauth2.php(567): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider->__construct()
#4 /var/www/osTicket/upload/include/plugins/auth-oauth2/oauth2.php(85): GenericOauth2Provider->getClient()
#5 /var/www/osTicket/upload/include/plugins/auth-oauth2/oauth2.php(473): OAuth2EmailAuthBackend->__construct()
#6 /var/www/osTicket/upload/include/plugins/auth-oauth2/oauth2.php(496): OAuth2ProviderBackend->getEmailAuthBackend()
#7 /var/www/osTicket/upload/scp/emails.php(100): OAuth2ProviderBackend->triggerEmailAuth()
#8 {main} thrown in /var/www/osTicket/upload/include/plugins/auth-oauth2/lib/GuzzleHttp/HandlerStack.php on line 42, referer: https://helpdesk.test/scp/emails.php?id=7

I have been at this for a few weeks now. I tried asking chatGPT regarding the error log and it told me to update the guzzlehttp to version 6.3 but that also doesn't work. What steps am I missing?
Now, I have no experience whatsoever with setting up OAuth and this is my first time doing so so apologies in advance
